# How to get rank by a column value with condithons in another column?

Tags: r

```
> df <- data.frame(
+   name = c("Jordan", "Kobe", "Iverson", "T-mac"),
+   value = c(23, 24, 3, 1)
+ )

> df
     name value
1  Jordan    23
2    Kobe    24
3 Iverson     3
4   T-mac     1
> 
> (df %>% mutate(rank.value = rank(-value)) %>% 
    filter(name== "Jordan") %>% 
    select(rank.value))[[1,1]]
[1] 2
```

I want to get the rank by value which name is Jordan.
I can get it with the complicated method above.

any simpler or better method to get it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is any simpler:

```
order(-df[,2])[which(df[,1]=="Jordan")]

#[1] 2
```

Comment: Using `df[,1]` is unnecessary. You can use `df` instead

Comment: You're right, but I'm assuming that this is a toy example and in the actual problem the value column may not be the first column, in which case it's needed.